# Efficient Way of Searching for a Value in a Nested Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, search

If I have a list of nested dictionaries of arbitrary length that look something like this:

```
list_of_dic = [{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': {'name': 'some_name1', ...}},
               {'A': 4, 'B': 1, 'C': {'name': 'some_name2', ...}},
               {'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': {'name': 'some_name3', ...}},
               ...]
```

And I want to find the nested dictionary (i.e. the dictionary associated with the key `C`) that contains the `name` I want (each `name` is unique; there are no duplicates), what is the most efficient way to do this?

I can think of 2 methods; the first is to just loop through everything, which sounds like a terrible way to do this, and the second is this:

```
[x['C'] for x in list_of_dic if x['C']['name'] == 'some_name5'][0]
```

Is there a better, more efficient way to do this, because `list_of_dic` has the potential to be quite long. Thank you.

Comment: Looks good to me. It's a single pass of the list, but I'm not sure I understand the `[0]` index. You might be better with a `for` loop with a `break` if you only want the first result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your approach, you would end up iterating through the entire list_of_dict even after a match is found.

You can use `next` to get only the first match

```
next((x['C'] for x in list_of_dic if x['C']['name'] == 'some_name5'), None)
```